# Where does this Python script go in the __init__py file?

Tags: python, azure, function, azure-functions

So I am trying to create my first Azure function. I am currently following a tutorial online. I managed to create an environment, install the necessary packages via Visual Studio Code. I actually have my Python script which looks like this:

```
import sqlalchemyimport pandas as pd

sqlcon = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql://LBCUCRDBS100TL/AdventureWorks?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server') 

path=r'C:\Users\H\Desktop\Correspondence\Correspondence_Received_with_Types.xlsx'

df=pd.read_excel(path)

df.to_sql('Correspondence',sqlcon,if_exists='append', index=False)

SQLQuery1="UPDATE Correspondence SET [Response By] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (REPLACE(REPLACE([Response By], 'Junaid Dar', 'Robson de Souza') , 'Jade Buckingham','Rivaldo Vitor Borba Ferreira'), 'Danielle Wallace','Ronaldo de Assis Moreira'), 'Sadiya Nurmahomed','Wayne Mark Rooney'),'Tendai Giwa','Joseph John Cole'), 'Tiffany Heslop', 'Lionel Andrés Messi'), 'Gareth Budiar','Steven George Gerrard'),'Jeneen Nicholson','Samuel Eto''o Fils'), 'James Beaton','Carlos Alberto Tevez'), 'Kirsty Moore','Vincent Jean Mpoy Kompany'),'Kelly McDonald','Leroy Aziz Sané'), 'Muzaffer Mehmet','Gareth Frank Bale'), 'Charmaine Banerji','Ronaldo Luís Nazário de Lima'),'Paul Hunt','Luís Carlos Almeida de Cunha'), 'Jessica Ararat-David', 'Dimitar Ivanov Berbatov'), 'Anita Hayler','José María Gutiérrez Hernández'), 'Vishal Chandel','Diego Armando Maradona'), 'Saleema Panjwani','Edson Arantes do Nascimento'), 'Mohammed Uddin','Thierry Daniel Henry'),'Edward Ford','Nicolas Sébastien Anelka'), 'Gillian Sutherland', 'Zinedine Yazid Zidane'), 'Abdul Jimoh','Gabriel Omar Batistuta'),'Lee Woolward','Emmanuel Laurent Petit'), 'Antonia Akintaju','Robert Emmanuel Pires'),'Maria Dayang','Roberto Carlos da Silva Rocha'), 'Latisha McFarlane','David Robert Joseph Beckham'), 'Janine Townsend', 'Francesco Totti'), 'Vaughan Anderson-Moore','Alessandro Del Piero')"
SQLQuery2="UPDATE Correspondence SET [CPZ Name] =  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (REPLACE(REPLACE([CPZ Name], 'North Camberwell', 'Dorne') , 'South Rotherhithe','King’s Landing'), 'Thorburn Square','Dragonstone'), 'All Non CPZ highway south of South Circular Road (A205)','Braavos'),'Housing Estates', 'Crownlands'), 'Parks Car Park', 'Winterfell'), 'South East Walworth', 'The Iron Islands'),'R - North Peckham','Casterly Rock'), 'CCTV Camera','Lannisport'),'Herne Hill', 'Volantis'),'South Camberwell', 'The Westerlands'),'South Bermondsey','Riverrun'), 'Rotherhithe', 'Highgarden'), ' Bankside','Storm’s End'), 'Trafalgar','The Kingsroad'), 'North Dulwich and Denmark Hill', 'Ashemark'), 'All Non CPZ highway north of South Circular Road (A205)','Blackmont'),'North Dulwich and Denmark Hill', 'Asshai'),'Newington', 'Doune Castle'), 'Peckham Road South', 'Horn Hill'),'South East Bermondsey', 'Banefort'), 'East dulwich','Red Keep'), ' East Camberwell', 'South Park'), 'Car Parks', 'Springfield'), 'Borough', 'Hogwarts'), 'Lucas Gardens', 'Neverland'), 'Peckham West', 'Gotham City'), ' East Camberwell', 'Wonderland'), 'Dog Kennel Hill', 'Stars Hollow'), 'West Walworth', 'Jurassic Park'), 'Bermondsey', 'Atlantis'), 'South Walworth', 'Asgard'), 'The Grange', 'The Shire'), 'London Bridge', 'Emerald City'), 'Walworth','Hogsmeade'), 'Peckham','Mordor'), 'Camberwell','Lilliput')"
SQLQuery3="UPDATE Correspondence SET [CPZ Code] =     CASE         WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'A' THEN 'A1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'B' THEN 'A2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'C1' THEN 'C1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'C2' THEN 'C2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 3 AND [CPZ Code] = 'CAM' THEN 'D1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'CP' THEN 'D2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'D' THEN 'E1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'E' THEN 'E2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'EC' THEN 'F1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'ED' THEN 'F2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'F' THEN 'G1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'G' THEN 'G2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'GR' THEN 'H1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'H' THEN 'H2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'HE' THEN 'I1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'HH' THEN 'I2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'J' THEN 'J1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'K' THEN 'J2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'L' THEN 'K1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'LG' THEN 'K2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'M1' THEN 'L1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'M2' THEN 'L2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'N' THEN 'M1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'NC' THEN 'M2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'P' THEN 'N1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 3 AND [CPZ Code] = 'PCP' THEN 'N2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'PR' THEN 'O1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'PW' THEN 'O2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'Q' THEN 'P1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'R' THEN 'P2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'SB' THEN 'Q1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 3 AND [CPZ Code] = 'SEB' THEN 'Q2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'T' THEN 'R1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'TS' THEN 'R2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'Z' THEN 'S1'        ELSE [CPZ Code]    END"
SQLQuery4="UPDATE Correspondence SET [Ticket #]=CONCAT('A3',STUFF([Ticket #],1,2,'')) "

sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery1)
sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery2)
sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery3)
sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery4)
```

The default __init__py file looks like this:

```
import logging

import azure.function as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request')
    
    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
       try:
           req_body = req.get_json()
       except ValueError:
           pass
       else:
           name = req_body.get('name')
           
    if name:
       return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    else:
       return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please pass a name in the query string or in the request body",
            status_code=400
       )
```

I pasted my code in the azure function like so:

```
import logging

import azure.function as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request')
    
    import sqlalchemy
    import pandas as pd


    sqlcon = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql://LBCUCRDBS100TL/AdventureWorks?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server') 

    path=r'C:\Users\H\Desktop\Correspondence\Correspondence_Received_with_Types.xlsx'

    df=pd.read_excel(path)

    df.to_sql('Correspondence',sqlcon,if_exists='append', index=False)

    SQLQuery1="UPDATE Correspondence SET [Response By] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (REPLACE(REPLACE([Response By], 'Junaid Dar', 'Robson de Souza') , 'Jade Buckingham','Rivaldo Vitor Borba Ferreira'), 'Danielle Wallace','Ronaldo de Assis Moreira'), 'Sadiya Nurmahomed','Wayne Mark Rooney'),'Tendai Giwa','Joseph John Cole'), 'Tiffany Heslop', 'Lionel Andrés Messi'), 'Gareth Budiar','Steven George Gerrard'),'Jeneen Nicholson','Samuel Eto''o Fils'), 'James Beaton','Carlos Alberto Tevez'), 'Kirsty Moore','Vincent Jean Mpoy Kompany'),'Kelly McDonald','Leroy Aziz Sané'), 'Muzaffer Mehmet','Gareth Frank Bale'), 'Charmaine Banerji','Ronaldo Luís Nazário de Lima'),'Paul Hunt','Luís Carlos Almeida de Cunha'), 'Jessica Ararat-David', 'Dimitar Ivanov Berbatov'), 'Anita Hayler','José María Gutiérrez Hernández'), 'Vishal Chandel','Diego Armando Maradona'), 'Saleema Panjwani','Edson Arantes do Nascimento'), 'Mohammed Uddin','Thierry Daniel Henry'),'Edward Ford','Nicolas Sébastien Anelka'), 'Gillian Sutherland', 'Zinedine Yazid Zidane'), 'Abdul Jimoh','Gabriel Omar Batistuta'),'Lee Woolward','Emmanuel Laurent Petit'), 'Antonia Akintaju','Robert Emmanuel Pires'),'Maria Dayang','Roberto Carlos da Silva Rocha'), 'Latisha McFarlane','David Robert Joseph Beckham'), 'Janine Townsend', 'Francesco Totti'), 'Vaughan Anderson-Moore','Alessandro Del Piero')"
    SQLQuery2="UPDATE Correspondence SET [CPZ Name] =  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (REPLACE(REPLACE([CPZ Name], 'North Camberwell', 'Dorne') , 'South Rotherhithe','King’s Landing'), 'Thorburn Square','Dragonstone'), 'All Non CPZ highway south of South Circular Road (A205)','Braavos'),'Housing Estates', 'Crownlands'), 'Parks Car Park', 'Winterfell'), 'South East Walworth', 'The Iron Islands'),'R - North Peckham','Casterly Rock'), 'CCTV Camera','Lannisport'),'Herne Hill', 'Volantis'),'South Camberwell', 'The Westerlands'),'South Bermondsey','Riverrun'), 'Rotherhithe', 'Highgarden'), ' Bankside','Storm’s End'), 'Trafalgar','The Kingsroad'), 'North Dulwich and Denmark Hill', 'Ashemark'), 'All Non CPZ highway north of South Circular Road (A205)','Blackmont'),'North Dulwich and Denmark Hill', 'Asshai'),'Newington', 'Doune Castle'), 'Peckham Road South', 'Horn Hill'),'South East Bermondsey', 'Banefort'), 'East dulwich','Red Keep'), ' East Camberwell', 'South Park'), 'Car Parks', 'Springfield'), 'Borough', 'Hogwarts'), 'Lucas Gardens', 'Neverland'), 'Peckham West', 'Gotham City'), ' East Camberwell', 'Wonderland'), 'Dog Kennel Hill', 'Stars Hollow'), 'West Walworth', 'Jurassic Park'), 'Bermondsey', 'Atlantis'), 'South Walworth', 'Asgard'), 'The Grange', 'The Shire'), 'London Bridge', 'Emerald City'), 'Walworth','Hogsmeade'), 'Peckham','Mordor'), 'Camberwell','Lilliput')"
    SQLQuery3="UPDATE Correspondence SET [CPZ Code] =     CASE         WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'A' THEN 'A1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'B' THEN 'A2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'C1' THEN 'C1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'C2' THEN 'C2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 3 AND [CPZ Code] = 'CAM' THEN 'D1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'CP' THEN 'D2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'D' THEN 'E1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'E' THEN 'E2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'EC' THEN 'F1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'ED' THEN 'F2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'F' THEN 'G1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'G' THEN 'G2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'GR' THEN 'H1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'H' THEN 'H2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'HE' THEN 'I1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'HH' THEN 'I2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'J' THEN 'J1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'K' THEN 'J2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'L' THEN 'K1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'LG' THEN 'K2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'M1' THEN 'L1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'M2' THEN 'L2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'N' THEN 'M1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'NC' THEN 'M2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'P' THEN 'N1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 3 AND [CPZ Code] = 'PCP' THEN 'N2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'PR' THEN 'O1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'PW' THEN 'O2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'Q' THEN 'P1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'R' THEN 'P2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'SB' THEN 'Q1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 3 AND [CPZ Code] = 'SEB' THEN 'Q2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'T' THEN 'R1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'TS' THEN 'R2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'Z' THEN 'S1'        ELSE [CPZ Code]    END"
    SQLQuery4="UPDATE Correspondence SET [Ticket #]=CONCAT('A3',STUFF([Ticket #],1,2,'')) "

    sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery1)
    sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery2)
    sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery3)
    sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery4)


 
    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
       try:
           req_body = req.get_json()
       except ValueError:
           pass
       else:
           name = req_body.get('name')
           
    if name:
       return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    else:
       return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please pass a name in the query string or in the request body",
            status_code=400
       )
```

When editing the code in Visual Studio Code I actually do not get an error but when I called the Azure function nothing happens. I was expecting it to access the SQL database and update the data.

Comment: How you are calling this function?

Comment: I am calling the function using Power Automate. They have a HTTP connector. Just out of curiosity, is the structure of the Python script correct?.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, this might be because for the code you have used. Make sure you place all the import statements at the top and run the azure functions. Make sure you are actually sending the HTTP request by hitting the function and giving the name while calling the function as per your code. Below is how it should look like,

```
import logging
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
import azure.function as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request')
    
    name = req.params.get('name')
    
    sqlcon = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql://LBCUCRDBS100TL/AdventureWorks?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server') 

    path=r'C:\Users\H\Desktop\Correspondence\Correspondence_Received_with_Types.xlsx'

    df=pd.read_excel(path)

    df.to_sql('Correspondence',sqlcon,if_exists='append', index=False)

    SQLQuery1="UPDATE Correspondence SET [Response By] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (REPLACE(REPLACE([Response By], 'Junaid Dar', 'Robson de Souza') , 'Jade Buckingham','Rivaldo Vitor Borba Ferreira'), 'Danielle Wallace','Ronaldo de Assis Moreira'), 'Sadiya Nurmahomed','Wayne Mark Rooney'),'Tendai Giwa','Joseph John Cole'), 'Tiffany Heslop', 'Lionel Andrés Messi'), 'Gareth Budiar','Steven George Gerrard'),'Jeneen Nicholson','Samuel Eto''o Fils'), 'James Beaton','Carlos Alberto Tevez'), 'Kirsty Moore','Vincent Jean Mpoy Kompany'),'Kelly McDonald','Leroy Aziz Sané'), 'Muzaffer Mehmet','Gareth Frank Bale'), 'Charmaine Banerji','Ronaldo Luís Nazário de Lima'),'Paul Hunt','Luís Carlos Almeida de Cunha'), 'Jessica Ararat-David', 'Dimitar Ivanov Berbatov'), 'Anita Hayler','José María Gutiérrez Hernández'), 'Vishal Chandel','Diego Armando Maradona'), 'Saleema Panjwani','Edson Arantes do Nascimento'), 'Mohammed Uddin','Thierry Daniel Henry'),'Edward Ford','Nicolas Sébastien Anelka'), 'Gillian Sutherland', 'Zinedine Yazid Zidane'), 'Abdul Jimoh','Gabriel Omar Batistuta'),'Lee Woolward','Emmanuel Laurent Petit'), 'Antonia Akintaju','Robert Emmanuel Pires'),'Maria Dayang','Roberto Carlos da Silva Rocha'), 'Latisha McFarlane','David Robert Joseph Beckham'), 'Janine Townsend', 'Francesco Totti'), 'Vaughan Anderson-Moore','Alessandro Del Piero')"
    SQLQuery2="UPDATE Correspondence SET [CPZ Name] =  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (REPLACE(REPLACE([CPZ Name], 'North Camberwell', 'Dorne') , 'South Rotherhithe','King’s Landing'), 'Thorburn Square','Dragonstone'), 'All Non CPZ highway south of South Circular Road (A205)','Braavos'),'Housing Estates', 'Crownlands'), 'Parks Car Park', 'Winterfell'), 'South East Walworth', 'The Iron Islands'),'R - North Peckham','Casterly Rock'), 'CCTV Camera','Lannisport'),'Herne Hill', 'Volantis'),'South Camberwell', 'The Westerlands'),'South Bermondsey','Riverrun'), 'Rotherhithe', 'Highgarden'), ' Bankside','Storm’s End'), 'Trafalgar','The Kingsroad'), 'North Dulwich and Denmark Hill', 'Ashemark'), 'All Non CPZ highway north of South Circular Road (A205)','Blackmont'),'North Dulwich and Denmark Hill', 'Asshai'),'Newington', 'Doune Castle'), 'Peckham Road South', 'Horn Hill'),'South East Bermondsey', 'Banefort'), 'East dulwich','Red Keep'), ' East Camberwell', 'South Park'), 'Car Parks', 'Springfield'), 'Borough', 'Hogwarts'), 'Lucas Gardens', 'Neverland'), 'Peckham West', 'Gotham City'), ' East Camberwell', 'Wonderland'), 'Dog Kennel Hill', 'Stars Hollow'), 'West Walworth', 'Jurassic Park'), 'Bermondsey', 'Atlantis'), 'South Walworth', 'Asgard'), 'The Grange', 'The Shire'), 'London Bridge', 'Emerald City'), 'Walworth','Hogsmeade'), 'Peckham','Mordor'), 'Camberwell','Lilliput')"
    SQLQuery3="UPDATE Correspondence SET [CPZ Code] =     CASE         WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'A' THEN 'A1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'B' THEN 'A2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'C1' THEN 'C1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'C2' THEN 'C2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 3 AND [CPZ Code] = 'CAM' THEN 'D1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'CP' THEN 'D2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'D' THEN 'E1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'E' THEN 'E2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'EC' THEN 'F1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'ED' THEN 'F2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'F' THEN 'G1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'G' THEN 'G2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'GR' THEN 'H1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'H' THEN 'H2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'HE' THEN 'I1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'HH' THEN 'I2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'J' THEN 'J1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'K' THEN 'J2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'L' THEN 'K1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'LG' THEN 'K2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'M1' THEN 'L1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'M2' THEN 'L2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'N' THEN 'M1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'NC' THEN 'M2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'P' THEN 'N1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 3 AND [CPZ Code] = 'PCP' THEN 'N2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'PR' THEN 'O1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'PW' THEN 'O2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'Q' THEN 'P1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'R' THEN 'P2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'SB' THEN 'Q1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 3 AND [CPZ Code] = 'SEB' THEN 'Q2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'T' THEN 'R1'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 2 AND [CPZ Code] = 'TS' THEN 'R2'        WHEN LEN([CPZ Code]) = 1 AND [CPZ Code] = 'Z' THEN 'S1'        ELSE [CPZ Code]    END"
    SQLQuery4="UPDATE Correspondence SET [Ticket #]=CONCAT('A3',STUFF([Ticket #],1,2,'')) "

    sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery1)
    sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery2)
    sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery3)
    sqlcon.execute(SQLQuery4)

    if not name:
       try:
           req_body = req.get_json()
       except ValueError:
           pass
       else:
           name = req_body.get('name')
           
    if name:
       return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    else:
       return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please pass a name in the query string or in the request body",
            status_code=400
       )
```

To run azure function and make a call to your HTTP Function

[image]

You can use the below url to call your function.

```
http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1?name=someName
```

If you are running through power automate make sure you pass a name to the function to get it called.